# Python tkinter radiobutton widget works in a single window, but not in multiple window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a question that I tried to solve for quite some time, but no success so far. When I use the code below with radiobuttons in a single window - everything works perfectly! I know exactly which radiobutton was pressed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def PressedRadio(var):
    global selection
    selection = var.get()
    print('Pushed the button!')
    print('var has value', selection)
    text_dict = {0: 'Nothing selected!', 1: 'Profile 1 selected', 2: 'Profile 2 selected', 3: 'Profile 3 selected',
                 4: 'profile 4 selected'}
    text_to_print = text_dict[selection]
    print(text_to_print)

def tutorial():

    tut = tk.Tk()
    tut.wm_title("Tutorial")
    label=ttk.Label(tut, text="What do you need help with?")

    var = IntVar()
    profile_sel_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(tut, text='Profile Selection_1', variable=var, value=1)
    profile_sel_2 = ttk.Radiobutton(tut, text='Profile Selection_2', variable=var, value=2)
    profile_sel_3 = ttk.Radiobutton(tut, text='Profile Selection_3', variable=var, value=3)
    profile_sel_4 = ttk.Radiobutton(tut, text='Profile Selection_4', variable=var, value=4)
    ser_port_btn = ttk.Button(tut, text='ENTER', command=lambda:PressedRadio(var))
    profile_sel_1.grid(row=4, column=0)
    profile_sel_2.grid(row=4, column=1)
    profile_sel_3.grid(row=4, column=2)
    profile_sel_4.grid(row=4, column=3)
    ser_port_btn.grid(row=5, column=3)

    tut.mainloop()

tutorial()
```

However when I use exactly the same code inserted to a multiple window application, where I call the tutorial from the help menu (see below), the var parameter of Radiobutton does not change anymore. I just started with programming, so maybe I have an obvious mistake in the code. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.
P.S. I don't know if it matters but I am using Pycharm on Mac

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def PressedRadio(var):
    selection = var.get()
    print('Pushed the button!')
    print('var has value', selection)
    text_dict = {0: 'Nothing selected!', 1: 'Profile 1 selected', 2: 'Profile 2 selected', 3: 'Profile 3 selected',
                 4: 'profile 4 selected'}
    text_to_print = text_dict[selection]
    print(text_to_print)

def tutorial():

    tut = tk.Tk()
    tut.wm_title("Tutorial")
    label=ttk.Label(tut, text="What do you need help with?")

    var = IntVar()
    profile_sel_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(tut, text='Choice 1', variable=var, value=1)
    profile_sel_2 = ttk.Radiobutton(tut, text='Choice 2', variable=var, value=2)
    profile_sel_3 = ttk.Radiobutton(tut, text='Choice 3', variable=var, value=3)
    profile_sel_4 = ttk.Radiobutton(tut, text='Choice 4', variable=var, value=4)
    ser_port_btn = ttk.Button(tut, text='ENTER', command=lambda:PressedRadio(var))
    profile_sel_1.grid(row=4, column=0)
    profile_sel_2.grid(row=4, column=1)
    profile_sel_3.grid(row=4, column=2)
    profile_sel_4.grid(row=4, column=3)
    ser_port_btn.grid(row=5, column=3)

    tut.mainloop()

class Myapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "My app")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit")
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        helpmenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="Tutorial", command=tutorial)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        self.frames={}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame=F(container, self)
            self.frames[F]=frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page One")
        label.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Go to page 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page One")
        label.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

app=Myapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is one of the many screwy things that happen when you call `Tk()` more than once (once implicitly in `Myapp`, once explicitly in `tutorial`).  You have to use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As told by @jasonharper, the main error is to call `Tk()` twice in your program. Calling `Tk()` initializes the tcl/tk engine running behind the scene when working with `tkinter`, and strange things happen with running two different engines.

But I would also suggest another modification : in your current code, the user may click on tutorial as many time as he wishes, launching an arbitrary number of popup windows, which is rarely desirable. So you may transform your popup into a **modal** window (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)) to avoid this behavior. Here is the modified code:

```
def tutorial():

    tut = tk.Toplevel()            # instead of tut = tk.Tk()
    tut.wm_title("Tutorial")

    ... same as previously ...

    tut.grab_set()                 # define popup as foreground window
    tut.wait_window()              # instead of tut.mainloop()
```